# How to get NEW. value dynamically on MySQL Trigger / After Insert?

Tags: mysql, json, triggers, phpmyadmin

I need the create a log table with use trigger in MySql. I get the column names successfully. How i get column inserted value dynamically ? For example i want to use NEW.@current_column_name . But its give a syntax error. (error: column name not found).

i need the show this result : {"id":"1","product_code":"12","product_name":"test_name" } tihs json keys is my column name.

My sql is ;

```
BEGIN

DECLARE is_done INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE s_name varchar(100) DEFAULT "";

DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR

SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'stock';

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET is_done=1;

SET @json="{";
OPEN my_cursor;

get_list:LOOP

FETCH my_cursor INTO s_name;
IF is_done=1 THEN
LEAVE get_list;
END IF;


SET @json =CONCAT(@json, """" ,s_name, """" ,":","""" , NEW.@s_name  , """", ",");


END LOOP get_list;
CLOSE my_cursor;


SET @json =CONCAT(@json,"}");

INSERT INTO log_new(`table_name`, `table_row_id`, `old_json`) 
VALUES ('stock', NEW.id, @json);
END
```

the website I get support from: https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-cursor

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen a cursor in a trigger - generally there is no need since a trigger operates on FOR EACH ROW.. Please add table definitions sample data and expected outcome as text to the question..

Comment: i tried without Cursor but same result same error. And i edited my question

Comment: `NEW` is not a table. `NEW.column_name` is single solid name (think about it as it is a variable name with special prefix), not a combination of table alias and column name. So only dynamic SQL (prepared statement) may solve, but it is not allowed in triggers.

Comment: Ideologically data storing structure must be deterministic/static, and processing code must match. If you alter table's DDL you must alter all related constructions, including triggers.